# Inserting customized Scroll Text

Tags: javascript, css, web, integration

I have downloaded and customized a scroll bar (with text), but I can't integrate it with my website.

Basically this is the code for the scroll bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery custom scrollbar demo</title>

<!-- Custom scrollbars CSS -->
<link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){
$("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
scrollButtons:{
enable:true
}
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
```

And I need to put in a page with this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/switcher.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sprites.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/googleMap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

It gives an error:

```
$("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar is not a function
```

Comment: what does the documentation of the downloaded scroll text says?

Comment: It's here
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller
He only tells about how to implement it, I didn't see nothing about conflicts

Comment: just to be sure, is there an element with `id="content_1"` and you double checked all the spelling? and you put the file in `js` directory and included it like `<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js">`??

Comment: I think I got it! I was checking everything and then I put the scroll code before the code that was already there and it's working! Just to understand it I put again the scroll code after the code of the main page and it didn't work again. Can someone explain why is it like that? Thanks for the support deathApril :)

Comment: what "scroll code"? you cannot use a function before importing its declaration / the function could have been overwritten by your code / the plugin needs to be placed on top for whatever reason / ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js" to the page.
And the "jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" to get the same styles.

Now add at the first line:

```
<link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You must add the jquery custom scrollbar, before you run the "$("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar()" function, and after the jquery library.

```
<script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
```